# Find control point order in spline

Tags: graphics, gdi+, spline

I'm currently working on a spline drawing tool for our software, and we want the ability to add a new control point to a spline. We're using a GDI+ GraphicsPath to draw the splines from a set of control points. Finding out whether a point is on the spline path is simple enough, but finding out in which order to add the new point so the existing spline passes through it is another matter.

We don't know how the curve itself is calculated, and at the moment only have the existing set of control points, the new point, and whether this point is on the curve path.

The only possible solution I could think of it to iteratively test whether the point is on a curve composed of the first 2, 3, 4.. points of the curve and from the observed results deduce between which existing points it belongs. This seems like a rather brute force way of solving the problem, so I was wondering if anyone knew of any better approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, this is what we did:

A Gdi+ GraphicsPath has a function to flatten the path into a series of points that form straight line segments, which seem to guarantee the inclusion of the original control points.

So we iterate through the set of flattened line segments, hit testing the new point against them, and keeping track of which 'control segment' we are in. When there's a hit, we found our target segment, and can add the new control point between the 2 defining that segment.

This is a brute force search, however I didn't find any other solutions that didn't require knowing how the spline is fitted to the points, and seems to runs smoothly even for complex splines.